# Has anyone got a version of Shaka player working with Cobalt

Tags: cobalt, shaka

I have been trying to run a simple shaka player test page based on the latest version from the repository using Cobalt release 11.

Using the debug version of shaka player currently I get the following console log:

```
[0301/112442:INFO:console.cc(52)] [console.log()] IndexedDB.install
[0301/112442:INFO:console.cc(52)] [console.log()] InputEvent.install
[0301/112442:INFO:console.cc(52)] [console.log()] mathRound.install
[0301/112442:INFO:console.cc(52)] [console.log()] MediaKeys.install
[0301/112442:INFO:console.cc(57)] [console.info()] Using native EME as-is.
[0301/112442:INFO:console.cc(52)] [console.log()] MediaSource.install
[0301/112442:INFO:console.cc(57)] [console.info()] Using native MSE as-is.
[0301/112442:INFO:console.cc(52)] [console.log()] VideoPlayPromise.install
[0301/112442:ERROR:console.cc(62)] [console.error()] VTTCue not available.
[0301/112442:INFO:browser_module.cc(534)] Loaded WebModule
[0301/112442:INFO:console.cc(52)] [console.log()] Unload latency:
[0301/112442:INFO:console.cc(52)] [console.log()] load() failed:
[0301/112442:ERROR:console.cc(62)] [console.error()] Error code
```

Has anyone been successful in getting shaka player work with the Cobalt Browser? If so could you please point me to the version used and what if any kind of modifications were made to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

We do not expect Shaka player to be working with Cobalt well. Cobalt supports subset of HTML5, CSS, JavaScript spec on purpose, and Shaka player is not built against Cobalt specs.

I am curious why you need Shaka player to be working on Cobalt but you can refer the modified Shaka player version from our Demo Player. https://yt-media-test.appspot.com/demo-player/dash-player-2018.html

Comment: Daniel is right, Shaka currently doesn't work on Cobalt because the latter doesn't support text tracks. That said, it's probably not too hard to work around that, so you can try your luck or, if you have a compelling business case, contact Shaka team.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. We are looking at using it for non-youtube dash playback for older STB's. We have dash.js working but dash.js seems to have issues with some of our streams (even in other browsers) so we wanted to integrate shaka player and compare the performance.